# Mongodb : Find and insert if time slots doesn't conflict with other time slots

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an event schema :

```
owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
participants: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
],
createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
lastModified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
active:{ type: Boolean, default: false },
eventDate: { type: Date },
startAt: { type: Date },
endAt : { type: Date },
timeZone:{ type: 'String', required: true }
```

I want to insert events such that the events dont overlap other events (for eg: if an event is on 2018-2-14 starting at 3:00 am and ending at 4:00 am, there should be no event on this date between 3:00 am and 4:00 am, other than this event. But there can be a event on this date for other time slots but not between 3:00 am to 4:00 am)

I tried the following logic but I didn't seem to work. Whats wrong with this logic:

```
const eventData = {
    owner: req
        .body
        .owner
        .trim(),
    startAt: setTimeToDate(req.body.eventDate, req.body.startAt.trim(), req.body.timeZone),
    endAt: setTimeToDate(req.body.eventDate, req.body.endAt.trim(), req.body.timeZone),
    eventDate: moment(req.body.eventDate).toISOString(),
    participants: req.body.participants,
    active: true,
    timeZone: req.body.timeZone
};

Events.find({
    $and: [
        {
            "eventDate": new Date(eventData.eventDate)
        }, {
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "startAt": {
                                $lt: new Date(eventData.startAt)
                            }
                        }, {
                            "startAt": {
                                $lte: new Date(eventData.endAt)
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "endtAt": {
                                $gte: new Date(eventData.startAt)
                            }
                        }, {
                                "endtAt": {
                                    $gt: new Date(eventData.endAt)
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                }
                ]
        }

        ]
})
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        const count = results.length;
        if (!count) {
            const newEvent = new Events(eventData);
            newEvent.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    res
                        .status(400)
                        .json({success: false, message: 'Could not create this availability.'});
                }
                res
                    .status(200)
                    .send({success: true, message: 'Your availability on this date is created successfully.'});
            });
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm not sure but I see two flaws in the logic

Basically you need any records which has startAt or endAt between your new startAt and endAt

in the first condition, You want the slots who have startAt time between new startAt and endAt, So for that the logic would be

```
startAt greater than new startAt and less than equal to new endAt
$and: [
                    {
                        "startAt": {
                            $gt: new Date(eventData.startAt)
                        }
                    }, {
                        "startAt": {
                            $lte: new Date(eventData.endAt)
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Also You want records which has endAt after new startAt and before new endAt, so for that logic would be

```
endAt greater than new startAt and less than equal to new endAt
    $and: [
                        {
                            "endAt": {
                                $gt: new Date(eventData.startAt)
                            }
                        }, {
                            "endAt": {
                                $lte: new Date(eventData.endAt)
                            }
                        }
                    ]
```

I think this would work.

**EDIT** Okay third condition would be, Slots that are starting before new StartAt and ending after new EndAt, Because they would not fall in above conditions

```
  $and: [
                            {
                                "startAt": {
                                    $lt: new Date(eventData.startAt)
                                }
                            }, {
                                "endAt": {
                                    $gt: new Date(eventData.endAt)
                                }
                            }
                        ]
```

Comment: I not just need any records between startAt or endAt time but also any record that overlaps with this time slot

Answer (score 3):

So what I did was to find out the chances that an event can overlap with other events.

The first case is when the start time of the new event that I'm gonna insert is between start time and end time of any other events.

The second case is similar and the only difference is this time I check if the end time of the new event that I'm gonna insert is between the start time and end time of any other events.

The third case is when the start time of the new event is less than the start time of any other events and the end time of new event is greater than the end time of any other events.

The 3 above scenarios cover all the cases of time slot overlappping
The query for the same is as shown below

```
{
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "startAt": {
                                $lte: new Date(new Date(eventData.startAt))
                            }
                        }, {
                            "endAt": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date(eventData.startAt))
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "startAt": {
                                $lte: new Date(new Date(eventData.endAt))
                            }
                        }, {
                            "endAt": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date(eventData.endAt))
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "startAt": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date(eventData.startAt))
                            }
                        }, {
                                "endAt": {
                                    $lte: new Date(new Date(eventData.endAt))
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                }
                ]
        }
```